# Are 1-Ups any good as rewards in Super Mario Maker 2?

Tags: super-mario-maker-2

I'm looking to reward the players of levels I make in Super Mario Maker 2 for finding secret areas, getting past difficult sections, etc.

In the original Super Mario Brothers series (Super Mario Brothers 3, Super Mario World, etc) the subjectively "best" reward was a 1-Up Mushroom, granting an extra life. Coins might be a second best as they granted points, and 100 coins would be a 1-Up.

In Super Mario Maker 2, from what I can tell, 1-Up Mushrooms have no value:  When I play courses locally through the "Play" option I haven't seen any counter for lives, and so getting an extra life seems to have no value (they're effectively infinite)

Do 1-Up mushrooms have any value in in Super Mario Maker 2? If not, what are good "rewards" to place in secret / difficult to find areas? What do players value and try to find?

Comment: ...I understand this question borders on subjective and have tried to make it fit the Stack Exchange style as best as I can!

Comment: I don't know if this is changed from Mario Maker 1 but 1-ups in that game only affect you if you're doing a 10x Life Challenge or something like that and only reward you the extra life if you beat the level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends.

If you have a somewhat challenging level it might end up in endless mode. 
There 1-Ups are at least a little bit of value, since you can collect 3 per level to add to your total live counter.
Especially for every mode past easy it is helpful to have your live counter stocked up for stages that require a few more tries.

In normal mode, where you can choose levels as you wish 1-ups are really not worth your time, as long as you did not set the win condition to collecting enough.

It may be better to reward your players with a mushroom or a fire flower here, since those are more versatile usable if you value normal play over endless modes.

But I personally would refrain from giving the player a movement improving item (like propeller mushroom, cape or tanookie leaf), since that is usually a way to break a level and get through it really fast without really admiring it.

Another way to reward a player for finding a secret area might be, that you set a win condition. If the player has to get a set amount of a special Item and he finds one or two of them in your secret area they don't have to look for them later on. That does work pretty good with 1-Up Mushrooms.

Comment: In general, it's common courtesy to always give the player access to three one-up mushrooms (or the equivalent in coins - i.e. 100 coins per one-up) in every level, for the benefit of those playing in Endless Mode. (As three one-ups is the cap for extra lives you can earn in that mode). Technically the most you can carry over in Endless Mode is 3 one-ups and 99 additional coins.

Answer (score 0):

You still can put an 1UP as a reward...

Although it's pointless if a player get into your course from random search, but 1UP will be a useful reward while your course been played in endless challenge mode.

Your question reminded me of putting some 1UP and some 10/30/50-coin in my course.

Answer (score 0):

**1-Ups are good for a reward if you are creating a Story map.**

---

#### The 1-Up Power-up

1-Ups are a free power-up that can grant a life to any character. If you are playing Online Mode (Nintendo Switch Online), they are awesome:

- **Story Maps.** 
  You can put a limited amount of lives in Story maps, and you can add a 1-Up to add a life, making this beneficial to passing levels.
- **Perfect Flags.** 
  If you jump on a flag perfectly in *any* game, you can get a 1-Up.
- **Overcomes Mushrooms.**
  Although a mushroom can give you a extra life *in game,* if you lose, the 1-Up can come in handy with a life for a whole game.

  ---

#### Sources

According to [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Are-1-Ups-any-good-as-rewards-in-Super-Mario-Maker-2), there are 6 answers about a 1-Up being beneficial.

---